# php 7 string to array convertion

Tags: magento-1, php-7.2

I have a little code to create an order which don't work with php7

```
foreach ($object['products'] as $productInfoSrc) {
        $productId = $productInfoSrc['product_id'];
        $qty = $productInfoSrc['qty'];
        $data['order']['add_products'][$productId] = array('qty' => $qty);
}
```

The line `$data['order']['add_products'][$productId] = array('qty' => $qty);` return me the bug php.

I try to make some correction like this :

```
    foreach ($object['products'] as $productInfoSrc) {
        $productId = $productInfoSrc['product_id'];
        $qty = $productInfoSrc['qty'];
        $data['order']['add_products']= array($productId, array('qty' => $qty);
}
```

but if I have 2 product, just 1 was taken by this code (i don't merge array i think).

someone can help me ?

Comment: Can you post the error message? Also can you post the result of <code>var_dump($productInfoSrc);</code>? Probably <code>$productId</code> is an array instead of string.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/139413)

Comment: As far I understand he has a php error in `$data['order']['add_products'][$productId] = array('qty' => $qty);` which is **array to string conversion**. So `$productId` has to be an array - which I typed in my answer. If he changes it, the script should work. Why this it not an answer?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have understood your problem, You are getting only one product information in variable `$data['order']['add_product']`

You can try below code

```
foreach ($object['products'] as $productInfoSrc) {
   $productId = $productInfoSrc['product_id'];
   $qty = $productInfoSrc['qty'];
   $data['order']['add_products'][]= array($productId, array('qty' => $qty);
}
```

I just added `[]` after `$data['order']['add_products']`.

Now you can dump this variable like below to check it data---

```
var_dump($data['order']['add_products'])
```

Please put comment if it works or you need something else.